Spring Boot Elasticsearch Pagination And Sorting won't sort 'text' type fields in ElasticSearch
In Spring Boot Elasticsearch Repository, I am using the PaginationAndSorting Spring capability (Pagination), which works great for fields that are 'date', but causes an error when I try to sort by a 'text' field.  Is this behavior expected or is there something I can do to fix it so that I can sort by all field types.
LogstashLogRepository.java:
public interface LogstashLogRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<LogstashLog, String> {
   
    /**
     * Repository's findByLevel does a query for all LogstashLogs with given level.
     * @param logstashLevel level to match, choices are SECURITY and ACTIVITY.
     * @return LogstashLogs with matching level.
     */
    @Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"level\": \"?0\"}}]}}")
    Page<LogstashLog> findByLevel(LogstashLog.LogstashLevel logstashLevel, Pageable pageable);
}

LogstashLogController.java:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class LogstashLogController {

    /**
     * Object mapper.
     */
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    /**
     * Spring Boot ES Repository.
     */
    @Autowired
    private LogstashLogRepository logstashLogRepository;

   

    /**
     * Retrieves all Logstash logs by level.
     *
     * @param levelRequest level requested.
     * @return ResponseEntity.
     */
    @Operation(summary = "Retrieve all Logstash logs specified by a level.")
    @GetMapping("/level")
    public ResponseEntity<List<LogstashLog>> findLogstashLogsByLevel(@RequestBody final LogstashLog.LogstashLevel levelRequest,
                                                               @PageableDefault(size = 20) final Pageable pageable) {
        Page<LogstashLog> pagedLogstashLogs = logstashLogRepository.findByLevel(levelRequest, pageable);
        List<LogstashLog> logstashLogs = pagedLogstashLogs.stream().toList();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(logstashLogs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

LogstashLog.java (model/dto):
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Document(indexName = "logstash-log")
public class LogstashLog {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @JsonAlias("@timestamp")
    @Field(name = "@timestamp")
    private Instant timestamp;

    @JsonAlias("Class")
    @JsonProperty("class")
    @Field(name = "class")
    private String loggingClass;

    @JsonAlias("Level")
    private LogstashLevel level;

    @JsonAlias("Date")
    private Instant date;

    @JsonAlias("Data")
    private LogstashLogData data;

    public enum LogstashLevel {
        SECURITY,
        ACTIVITY
    }
}

mapping for the metadata in elastic search (I use an elk stack, so this data is put in via logstash)
 "logstash-log": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "properties": {
            "message": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "user": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "event": {
          "properties": {
            "original": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "level": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

If I use timestamp (or date), I can sort just fine, and get back something like this:
[
    {
        "id": "aafC544C-o-vp9msel90",
        "timestamp": "2024-04-16T16:34:25.916453227Z",
        "level": "SECURITY",
        "date": "2024-04-16T16:34:25.914062Z",
        "data": {
            "user": "John Smith",
            "message": "Title Security Chicken"
        },
        "class": "com.example.ExampleController"
    },
    {
        "id": "ZqfC544C-o-vp9msel9c",
        "timestamp": "2024-04-16T16:34:25.908138479Z",
...

But if I try to sort by class (or id, or level, etc.), I get:
Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed] with root cause","exception":"co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed ....
I have modified LogstashRepository to not return anything with Pagination and instead tried to do it on the results. But since I use a @Query annotation instead of a NativeSearchQuery, I'm afraid that there's not much I can do to the results since they're not recognized as a type of Query.  Do I have to switch to using Query itself instead of the annotation so I can use ES's sort instead of Pagination's sort?

The answer for this was stupidly simple.  Elasticsearch can't sort on text unless you tell it to via fielddata=true (though they don't recommend this method) or change it to a type keyword instead of text -- both would require a fix to how logstash enters the data.
Alternatively, the search itself could just say "*.keyword", so in my case "class.keyword" will correctly do the Sort.
